# How to pass script path to Python 3.9 on Windows 10?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, command-line-arguments

From Windows 10 command line , Python 3.9.13, in directory:

```
C:\Users\foo.bar\wks\df\data
```

when trying to run :

```
python unilm\\layoutlm\\examples\\seq_labeling\\preprocess.py --data_dir FUNSD\\training_data\\annotations --data_split train --output_dir data --model_name_or_path microsoft/layoutlm-base-uncased --max_len 510
```

I get this error:

```
python: can't open file 'C:\Users\foo.bar\wks\df\data\unilm\layoutlm\examples\seq_labeling\preprocess.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Notwithstanding the path `C:\Users\foo.bar\wks\df\data\unilm\layoutlm\examples\seq_labeling\preprocess.py'` is correct, really exists.

What's wrong?

Comment: With a file path that complex, I'd triple check to make sure the file really exists at that path.

Comment: could the "." in "foo.bar" be messing things up?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this:

1. Use the -m flag:

python -m my_script.py

2. Use the sys.argv list:

import sys sys.argv.append('my_script.py')

3. Use the os.environ dictionary:

import os os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = 'my_script.py'

4. Use the site module:

import site site.addsitedir('my_script.py')

Comment: I need to run script from command line in this particular directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in a typo in one of the words of the long path to a script. Thanks for trying to help and sorry for confusion!